# Trailhead : Question on Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, trailhead

I have been following this exercise here.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/salesforce_developer_workshop/steps/creating_triggers

`Session__c` and `Speaker__c` are parent objects.

`Session_Speaker__c` is a junction object relating the above.

This is the email sending trigger that sends an email to the speaker as soon as they are assigned to a session.

```
trigger SendConfirmationEmail on Session_Speaker__c (after insert) {

        //collect ID's in one list of a single SOQL query
    List<Id> sessionSpeakerIds = new List<Id>();
    for(Session_Speaker__c newItem : trigger.new) {
        sessionSpeakerIds.add(newItem.Id);
    }

    // Retrieve session name and time + speaker name and email address related to ID's
    List<Session_Speaker__c> sessionSpeakers =
            [SELECT Session__r.Name,
                    Session__r.Session_Date__c,
                    Speaker__r.First_Name__c,
                    Speaker__r.Last_Name__c,
                    Speaker__r.Email__c
             FROM Session_Speaker__c WHERE Id IN :sessionSpeakerIds];

     if(sessionSpeakers.size() > 0) {
            // Send confirmation email if we know the speaker's email address
            Session_Speaker__c sessionSpeaker = sessionSpeakers[0];
            if (sessionSpeaker.Speaker__r.Email__c != null) {
                String address = sessionSpeaker.Speaker__r.Email__c;
                String subject = 'Speaker Confirmation';
                String message = 'Dear ' + sessionSpeaker.Speaker__r.First_Name__c +
                    ',\nYour session "' + sessionSpeaker.Session__r.Name + '" on ' +
                    sessionSpeaker.Session__r.Session_Date__c + ' is confirmed.\n\n' +
                    'Thanks for speaking at the conference!';
                EmailManager.sendMail(address, subject, message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe this trigger is not bulkified.

What if I load records into this junction object via dataloader, then this trigger will fire only for the first record in the incoming trigger collection.

Am I right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really lousy trailhead; not only does it not teach bulkification, it doesn't even show how real code would be written. A slightly better version would skip getting the list of ID values and just query the records directly:

```
for(Session_Speaker__c record: [SELECT Session__r.Name,
                Session__r.Session_Date__c,
                Speaker__r.First_Name__c,
                Speaker__r.Last_Name__c,
                Speaker__r.Email__c
         FROM Session_Speaker__c WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new
              AND Speaker__r.Email <> NULL]) {
  String address = sessionSpeaker.Speaker__r.Email__c;
  String subject = 'Speaker Confirmation';
  String message = 'Dear ' + sessionSpeaker.Speaker__r.First_Name__c +
                   ',\nYour session "' + sessionSpeaker.Session__r.Name + '" on ' +
                   sessionSpeaker.Session__r.Session_Date__c + ' is confirmed.\n\n' +
                   'Thanks for speaking at the conference!';
  EmailManager.sendMail(address, subject, message);
}
```

Now, of course, this code still isn't properly bulkified, because we still are sending one email per iteration, which runs into other governor limits pretty quickly, so we'd need to make a bulkified version of sendEmail as well.

```
public class EmailManager {
  public static void sendEmails(String[] addresses, String[] subjects, String[] messages) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
    for(Integer i = 0, s = addresses.size(); i < s; i++) {
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      email.setSubject(subjects[i]);
      email.setToAddresses(new List<String> { addresses[i] });
      email.setPlainTextBody(messages[i]);
      emails.add(email);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
  }
}
```

---

Which would allow us to change the trigger:

```
String[] addresses = new String[0],
  subjects = new String[0],
  messages = new String[0];
for(Session_Speaker__c record: [SELECT Session__r.Name,
                Session__r.Session_Date__c,
                Speaker__r.First_Name__c,
                Speaker__r.Last_Name__c,
                Speaker__r.Email__c
         FROM Session_Speaker__c WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new
              AND Speaker__r.Email <> NULL]) {
  addresses.add(sessionSpeaker.Speaker__r.Email__c);
  subjects.add('Speaker Confirmation');
  messages.add('Dear ' + sessionSpeaker.Speaker__r.First_Name__c +
                   ',\nYour session "' + sessionSpeaker.Session__r.Name + '" on ' +
                   sessionSpeaker.Session__r.Session_Date__c + ' is confirmed.\n\n' +
                   'Thanks for speaking at the conference!');
}
EmailManager.sendMails(addresses, subjects, messages);
```

Mind you, I'd still clean this up even further with objects and whatnot, but that's more advanced than you need to know as a beginner. Starting from a clean baseline of how to write good code is essential.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox...I have been doing SF for quite some time....The reason I posted it here is I really could not believe that they displayed a unbulkified trigger and that too in trailhead !! :)...So i thought I must be missing something as SF Trailhead folks would not do this such a glaring mistake...Anyways thanks for your inputs mate :)

Comment: @user2655970 Believe me, I plan on speaking to someone about this. It's unacceptable to have code like this as a beginner's tutorial, because it teaches bad habits up front.

Comment: posted this to trailhead in twitter https://twitter.com/krish_vamsi/status/964317798376685568. saved you sometime @sfdcfox so you can do another answer :-)

Comment: Not to mention the fact that one should keep the most possible code outside of triggers...

Comment: @JulienGaïotto As an "introduction to triggers", I don't necessarily agree that trigger frameworks should necessarily be covered. Basic techniques, like bulkification, should be covered at the beginner's level, though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct this trigger is not properly bulkified. A correct pattern would generate one `List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>` which includes all the emails you want to send (not just the first junction), then call `Messaging.sendEmail` just once. Your `EmailManager` does not currently appear to support this pattern based on the signature you currently call.